# Why does an async consumer called in __init__ in a Tornado RequestHandler behave differently from statically called?

Tags: python, asynchronous, tornado, consumer

I'm trying to make an async server using Tornado with a unique queue for each handler. A job is placed into a queue when the end point is called. I have a consumer function which asynchronously 'consumes' jobs from the queue. However, the behavior of consumer tends to vary depending on whether I call it as `self.consumer()` or `AsyncHandler.consumer()`. My initial guess is that it is because of instance level locking but can't find evidence for it. I fire 4 post requests consecutively. Here are the 2 snippets with their outputs.

```
import tornado.web
from tornado import gen
from time import sleep, time
from tornado.queues import Queue
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop

class AsyncHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):

    JOB_QUEUE = Queue()
    EXECUTOR = ThreadPoolExecutor()

    def post(self):
        job = lambda: sleep(3) or print("{}:handler called".format(int(time())))
        self.JOB_QUEUE.put(job)
        self.set_status(200)
        self.finish()

    @staticmethod
    @gen.coroutine
    def consumer():
        while True:
            job = yield AsyncHandler.JOB_QUEUE.get()
            print("qsize : {}".format(AsyncHandler.JOB_QUEUE.qsize()))
            print(AsyncHandler.JOB_QUEUE)
            output = yield AsyncHandler.EXECUTOR.submit(job)
            AsyncHandler.JOB_QUEUE.task_done()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    AsyncHandler.consumer()
    APP = tornado.web.Application([(r"/test", AsyncHandler)])
    APP.listen(9000)
    IOLoop.current().start()
```

This gives the expected output:

```
qsize : 0
<Queue maxsize=0 tasks=1>
1508618429:handler called
qsize : 2
<Queue maxsize=0 queue=deque([<function...<lambda> at 0x7fbf8f741400>, <function... <lambda> at 0x7fbf8f760ea0>]) tasks=3>
1508618432:handler called
qsize : 1
<Queue maxsize=0 queue=deque([<function AsyncHandler.post.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x7fbf8f760ea0>]) tasks=2>
1508618435:handler called
qsize : 0
<Queue maxsize=0 tasks=1>
1508618438:handler called
```

`output = yield AsyncHandler.EXECUTOR.submit(job)` takes 3 seconds to return output and so the outputs arrive at delay of 3 seconds. Also we can see the queue build up in the meanwhile.

Now to the interesting piece of code:

```
import tornado.web
from tornado import gen
from time import sleep, time
from tornado.queues import Queue
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop

class AsyncHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    JOB_QUEUE = Queue()
    EXECUTOR = ThreadPoolExecutor()

    def __init__(self, application, request, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(application, request, **kwargs)
        self.consumer()

    def post(self):
        job = lambda: sleep(3) or print("{}:handler called".format(int(time())))
        self.JOB_QUEUE.put(job)
        self.set_status(200)
        self.finish()

    @staticmethod
    @gen.coroutine
    def consumer():
        while True:
            job = yield AsyncHandler.JOB_QUEUE.get()
            print("qsize : {}".format(AsyncHandler.JOB_QUEUE.qsize()))
            print(AsyncHandler.JOB_QUEUE)
            output = yield AsyncHandler.EXECUTOR.submit(job)
            AsyncHandler.JOB_QUEUE.task_done()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    APP = tornado.web.Application([(r"/test", AsyncHandler)])
    APP.listen(9000)
    IOLoop.current().start()
```

The output weirdly (and pleasantly) looks like:

```
qsize : 0
<Queue maxsize=0 tasks=1>
qsize : 0
<Queue maxsize=0 tasks=2>
qsize : 0
<Queue maxsize=0 tasks=3>
qsize : 0
<Queue maxsize=0 tasks=4>
1508619138:handler called
1508619138:handler called
1508619139:handler called
1508619139:handler called
```

Note that now we're calling consumer inside `__init__`. We can see the tasks build up and execute in parallel (without a queue build up), completing almost simultaneously. It's as if `output = yield AsyncHandler.EXECUTOR.submit(job)` is not blocking on the future. Even after a lot of experimentation I'm unable to explain this behavior. I'd really appreciate some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first application has only one running `consumer` because it's executed once. Each request "blocks" (only one at a time is the loop) the consumer, so the next one will be processed after the previous.

The latter app starts a new `consumer` loop with each request (since RequestHandler is created per req). So the first request does not "block" the next one, 'cause there is brand new `while True` with `get` and `submit`...

Comment: I see it now that you mention it! Thanks! I confirmed it by printing the instance calling the consumer. So basically the while True loop should really just be a single consumer call.  My understanding is that all request handlers are executed in the main thread so multiple consumers shouldn't be a problem. Any particular downsides you can see to this approach ?